# MySQL INSERT Using Subquery with COUNT() on the Same Table

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-error-1093

I'm having trouble getting an `INSERT` query to execute properly, and I can't seem to find anything on Google or Stack Overflow that solves this particular issue.

I'm trying to create a simple table for featured entries, where the `entry_id` is saved to the table along with it's current order.

My desired output is this:

If the `featured` table currently has these three entries:

```
featured_id    entry_id    featured_order
1              27          0
2              54          1
4              23          2
```

I want the next entry to save with `featured_order`=3.

I'm trying to get the following query to work with no luck:

```
INSERT INTO `featured`
(
    `entry_id`, `featured_order`
)
VALUES
(
    200,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `the_count` FROM `featured`)
)
```

The error I'm getting is: `You can't specify target table 'featured' for update in FROM clause`.

Can anyone help with a solution that gets the count without causing an error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Not a duplicate - that question was for deletion; this is for insertion. Doesn't apply at all here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a cool thing: MySQL's [`INSERT . . . SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO `featured`
(
    `entry_id`, `featured_order`
)
SELECT 200, COUNT(*) + 1
FROM `featured`
```

No subquery required.

---

@Bohemian has a good point:

> Better to use max(featured_order) + 1 if you use this approach

So a better query would probably be:

```
INSERT INTO `featured`
(
    `entry_id`, `featured_order`
)
SELECT 200, MAX(`featured_order`) + 1
FROM `featured`
```

His trigger method describe in his answer is also a good way to accomplish what you want.

---

The potential problem with query 1 is if you ever delete a row the rank will be thrown off, and you'll have a duplicate in `featured_order`. With the second query this is not a problem, but you will have gaps, just as if you were using an auto-increment column.

If you absolutely must have an order with no gaps the best solution I know of is to run this series of queries:

```
SET @pos:=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 LIKE featured;

ALTER TABLE featured ORDER BY featured_order ASC;

INSERT INTO temp1 (featured_id, entry_id, featured_order) 
SELECT featured_id, entry_id, @pos:=@pos+1 FROM words;

UPDATE featured 
JOIN temp1 ON featured.featured_id = temp1.featured_id 
SET featured.rank = temp1.rank;

DROP TABLE temp1;
```

Whenever you delete a row

Comment: I don't think this will work. From the docs for [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html): "However, you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Comment: Problems with this: a) you'll want to add one to count(*), b) what if numbering doesn't align with count(*) - eg if rows get deleted. Better to use max(featured_order) + 1 if you use this approach

Comment: @JIStone - I admit I didn't try it. The documentation (this was for 5.5) seemed pretty clear. But then, it may be wrong. What version of MySQL did you use?

Comment: the SELECT statement in this example isn't considered a subquery.

Comment: It's very odd, since the warning about a subquery is on the manual page about INSERT...SELECT (as well as on the page about subquery syntax).

Comment: Very cool! I'd never seen `INSERT...SELECT` before. This worked for me using `MAX(featured_order) + 1` — I've got a plan to keep things sequenced properly that should work out alright. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use a trigger:

```
drop trigger if exists featured_insert_trigger; 

delimiter //
create trigger featured_insert_trigger before insert on featured
for each row
begin
  set new.featured_order = ifnull((select max(featured_order) from featured), -1) + 1;
end; //
delimiter ;
```

Now your inserts look like this:

```
insert into featured (entry_id) values (200);
```

`featured_order` will be set to the highest featured_order value plus one. This caters for rows being deleted/updated and always guarantee uniqueness.

The `ifnull` is there in case there are no rows in the table, in which case the first value will be zero.

This code has been tested as works correctly.

Comment: I did a little research on triggers (I'd never heard of them before), and this definitely sounds like the best solution.

However, when I tried it, I get this error:

`TRIGGER command denied to user 'xxxx'@'xxxx' for table 'featured'`

I've given the MySQL user "all privileges" according to HostGator, so it looks like a trigger isn't in the cards for this project. :/

Comment: Does this work if there are two inserts exactly at the same time?

Comment: @xms there are never any updates/inserts that happen at "exactly the same time". The database serialises all mutating queries. Each always starts and completes atomically.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO `featured`
(
    `entry_id`, `featured_order`
)
VALUES
(
    200,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `the_count` FROM `featured` F1)
)
```

Correction is just adding "F1" table alias.

This standard sql solution works fine on various dbms (not only mysql)

---

I also suggest an improvement over:

- SELECT COUNT(*) +1 (Problem: if some row gets deleted you may collide with existing index)
- SELECT MAX(featured_order)+1 (Problem: the first insert with empty table gets error)

**SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(featured_order), 0)+1) (no Problem)**

Comment: I was just wondering... Will this work just fine if there are two inserts exactly at the same time?

Comment: I think you're right, the "second" one should fail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to simpley use alias that will solve the problem :

```
INSERT INTO `featured`
(
    `entry_id`, `featured_order`
)
VALUES
(
    200,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `the_count` FROM `featured` as f1)
)
```

Comment: It would be better if explanation is provided along eith -vote which will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html) regarding subqueries:

> Another restriction is that currently you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Perhaps an alias or a join (otherwise useless) in the subquery would help here.

EDIT: It turns out that there's a work-around. The work-around is described http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/.

Comment: That 'work around" involves a subsequent `update` statement - hardly "elegant".

Comment: I hope I didn't imply "elegant" :)